# How do I keep Ender men out of my end shop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play on a small Minecraft server where I’m working on a shop in the end however the shop is a big glass dome with a high ceiling and I would like to keep the endermen out of the shop. How can I keep endermen from teleporting in? (Btw I know I can use a floor made of transparent blocks but that is my plan B in case there is no other way and a short ceiling isn’t an option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cover the floor in double carpets - two layers of carpet. The endermen don't spawn on it, don't consider that a valid teleport destination and don't pathfind over it unless they happen to get there accidentally e.g. after dropping off ledges. Another option is waterlogged blocks - in particular, waterlogged upside-down stairs and slabs provide regular flat surface, and normal stairs can be shaped into fancy patterns of half block wide water channels.

Note full-top blocks like stairs or slabs will stop teleportation and pathfinding but not spawns - the endermen can still spawn on them (and sit there confused). Regular orientation stairs and carpets are spawn-proof. Also, transparent blocks like glass or bottom slabs are spawn-proof but don't do a thing against teleportation or pathfinding.

Comment: Thank you I will definitely try water logging the floor

Comment: Another easy way to do it is just make the roof 2 blocks high so enderman can't teleport inside.

Comment: @nerdbegaming please see the edit.

Comment: Yes I noticed the fact that they can spawn on the turned over waterlogged blocks after I made the floor

Comment: @dabbingsdednow I already stated in the question that a low ceiling wasn’t an option

Comment: And to fix them spawning in my shop I have filled the room with torches because even in the end the light level must be below 7 to spawn